# Grouping RS like a menu

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have a table with bunch of news, all of them have published date, so I wanted to retrieve the result similar as some menus in blogs: ordered by year, inside year by month, and inside month the days.

```
2014
  January
    news1
    news2
  February
  March
2013
  January
  etc..
```

kind of a menu like blogspot or so

```
SELECT publishedon FROM News where parent=9999 group by publishedon;
```

I'm using php too, but I don't think I can have it grouped from mysql.